# How to display framerate in window title?

Tags: c++, directx

I think this is going to be an easy one for you guys :)

I am trying to get FPS displayed in the window title in my Directx application (written in C++). I do not really know how to do this as my app assigns title in this manner 
[image]

any ideas how to do this (so that I can see the FPS when I minimise my app) ?

Comment: Why do you need FPS when the window is minimized? It's not going to be rendering anything then...

Comment: i need fps while the windows is minimized cuz I need to now the GPU load (nevermind - it has to be this way because "client" wanted it like that)
i have window class which has  WNDCLASS windowClass; who has lpszClassName which is responsible for the title of the window but when I try to assign something to this it says that : expression must be a modifiable value :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `SetWindowText()` to accomplish this, e.g.:

```
HWND window = CreateWindow(windowClass.lpszClassName, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, x, y, width, height, GetDesktopWindow(),NULL,windowClass.hInstance,NULL);
```

... then later ...

```
SetWindowText(window, "XXXX FPS");
```

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302340.aspx#win32map_windowfunctions

Comment: hmmm... but the Window class is declared in the project. It's not the windows (.NET) Window class. :/ this is its code : http://www.copypastecode.com/71826/

Comment: So it looks like this is an API taken from a DX tutorial... shouldn't you be able to add a new function to the class that will allow you to change the window title? At some point it has to communicate with the underlying native windowing system, which does allow you to change the title.

Comment: I think you're going to use a call to `CreateWindow` inside the class somewhere, right? So, can't you use the return value of the `CreateWindow` call and call `SetWindowText()` on this?

Comment: Ok, so I edited my answer to make it a bit more clear what I mean.

Comment: thanks for this but I have window object being an instance of Window class (defined in the link above) so one cannot cast from Window to HWND. So this would be a good solution for a program which uses Microsoft window class ( and I do not want to remake whole app just for this :/)

Comment: But... at some point, your `Window` class probably calls `CreateWindow`, or am I missing something? I thought probably your code is taken from this tutorial: http://zophusx.byethost11.com/tutorial.php?lan=dx9&num=1